# Prolog - list of lists

Tags: prolog

Having  - `myMultiply/3`

```
myMultiply([],X,[]) :- !.
myMultiply([H|T],X,Result) :-
    myMultiply(T,X,NewRest),
    Elem is H*X,
    Result = [Elem|NewRest].
```

Which which mulply each element at the left list to the nun at 2nd arg and return `Result` .

For example -

```
myMultiply([1,4,5],4,R).
R = [4,16,20].
```

And   `tlm/3`

```
tlm(List1,[],_) :- !.
tlm(List1,[H2,Rest2],Result):-
    myMultiply(List1,H2, Elem),
    tlm(List1,Rest2,NewResult),
    Result = [Elem|NewResult].
```

Which there I trying to make  `myMultiply/3` to the left list on each element of the right list and retun `Result`  .

For example  -

```
?- tlm([3,4,2],[4,7,8],R).
R = [[12,16,8],[21,28,14],[24,32,16]].
```

Generally the idea is the get the `Elem` list and concat him to `NewResult` .

My problem is that `tlm/3` returns `false` -

```
 ?- tlm([3,4,2],[4,7,8],R).
false.
```

Instead of the above example .

What I did wrong here  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

Here I've done a basic correction, and commented about useless cuts.

```
myMultiply([],X,[]) :- !. % the cut is useless here
myMultiply([H|T],X,Result) :-
    myMultiply(T,X,NewRest),
    Elem is H*X,
    Result = [Elem|NewRest].

tlm(List1,[],[]) :- !. % the cut is useless here
tlm(List1,[H2|Rest2],Result):-
    myMultiply(List1,H2, Elem),
    tlm(List1,Rest2,NewResult),
    Result = [Elem|NewResult].
```

and the result is...

```
?- tlm([3,4,2],[4,7,8],R).
R = [[12, 16, 8], [21, 28, 14], [24, 32, 16]].
```

Could you spot why cuts are useless?

Comment: sure: `tlm(List1,[],[])` instead of `tlm(List1,[],_)` and `tlm(List1,[H2|Rest2],Result)` instead of `tlm(List1,[H2,Rest2],Result)`. Three characters...The second, in particular, was the cause of the `false` answer.